# Can I have two boot partitions on an SSD (UEFI)?

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, uefi, boot-partition

I wish to dual boot windows and pop!_os. My computer has windows 10 already installed, in the disk there is an ESP partition of 100MB followed by a microsoft reserved partition.

pop!_os requires that the boot partition be at least 512 MB. Most tutorials I found on the topic suggest (eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CozK7sJ8UMs) that I create another partition formatted to FAT32 and make pop!_os installer boot from that.

Does this mean that my disk will have two ESP partitions? I ask because I read somewhere that having two ESP's in the same drive is a big nono (source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16261237)

What problems can I face if I do this?

Note: I am already dual booting ubuntu and windows 10 but Ubuntu was okay with my existing small ESP partition (which I asked it to boot from)

Comment: IIRC you can delete the Microsoft Reserved Partition. It exists for this very reason anyway.

Comment: Microsoft considers System Reserved as required. It puts some system key type settings into it. Its your UEFI that may have issues, or in UEFI settings. But once boot set up, booting from both should work as UEFI boot entry uses partUUID/GUID to find entry, not partition type GUID. Just know how to move esp,boot flags back and forth, if you need to use UEFI. But if HP, you often have to use UEFI settings to change boot order, not sure then if it would work.

Comment: Works for me. I've even used one ESP per Windows installation (in VHDX) because I want to avoid the Windows Boot Manager boot menu but instead choose which Windows to boot with grub. (Recent) Windows 10 handles it quite well AFAIK (it "remembers" which ESP the WBM is loaded from, I think).